# Display problems when running window maker package

Tags: cygwin

I have display issues after installing wm on cygwin, is it a redrawing issue?

Here is a screenshot of wm running on a XWin server:

[image]

Comment: Are you using the Cygwin package ?

Comment: Yes I'm using the cygwin package